# Does gtag(GA4) takes long time(5s) to fire an event?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I did a test with google analytics event script.
This script takes 5 seconds to fire the event.(5 seconds lag):

`gtag('event','test',{'event_category':'evnt_cat'});`

And this one was fired imediately.

`ga('send','event','blabla','a','b')`

My questions are:
is it true?
why does google analytics add lag there?
and how can I fire it imediately?

here is the codes:

````
<head>
<title>test</title>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-*******"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-*******');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href='#' onclick="gtag('event','test',{'event_category':'evnt_cat','event_label':'label': true});return false;">test</a>
</body>
</html>```

Thanks for your time.
````

Answer (score 1):

I believe ga4 buffers events and waits about 5 seconds or when the page is unloading to fire them using a beacon. This would probably be to avoid interfering with the users' experience and reduce network traffic.